# What is the correct converter to fit my Inoxcrom fountain pen?

Tags: ink, pens

My grandfather left me an old Inoxcrom fountain pen that was given to him as a gift. I have been using it as a dip pen to write with, but am hoping to find a converter so I can use it on the go. I am not interested in cartridges.

I can't seem to find the model of this pen online, and it doesn't seem to fit the standard cartridge/converter size. The reason I say this is because I bought a fountain pen from an old man who hand makes them, and I suspect he sizes them to international cartridge/converter sizes.

Here are some photos of the pen:

[image: Nib says Inoxcrom Iridum, ring around barrel says Inoxcrom, Spain written on gold part of lid]
Nib says Inoxcrom Iridum, ring around barrel says Inoxcrom, Spain written on gold part of lid.

[image: No logos or symbols on ends of cap or pen]
There are no logos or symbols on ends of cap or pen.

Comment: Can you add a picture with the pen disassembled?

Comment: Hey Ribika. :D We won't be able to direct you at a specific shop, but if we have some people who know about pens, they may be able to tell you what kind of converter you need.

Comment: Would you be open to buying a small pack of cartridges to test fit? IME there are three common sizes: Parker (long, also used by others), Lamy (long) and almost everyone else (short).  I've used a paerker reservoir in a Lamy before.

Comment: Well, get in contact with Inoxcrom themselves: http://inoxcrom.com/en/ They love Collectors and collections, I'm quite sure they'll be more than happy to help you. Good luck!

Comment: @MarcoAntónio that link seems broken?

Comment: Ribika, what do you mean by "standard" converter size? (Compare @ChrisH's comment.)

Comment: Can you find out what the diameter and length of the barrel is?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like everything online says these use the Standard International size cartridge. There are some complaints of leaks though unless you get them from the original maker.

If you have an old original cartridge, you could try cleaning and refilling it.